# jQuery ie input text issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have the following weird issue with the "loading gif" that I want to display in my search bar when the user hits enter. The code works on mozilla and ie 7 on the localhost but only on mozilla on my cpanel...
Do you have any clue?? Sorry if this looks obvious :)
here is the code, the path is dynamic but of course correct:

```
$('#searchField').focus(function(){
        $(this).keypress(function(event) {
            if ( event.which == 13 ) {
                $(this).css('background-image', 'url("/dvt/public/images/ajaxLoader.gif")');
            }
        });
    });
```

thanks a lot

Comment: try to use `event.keyCode` instead of `event.which`

Answer (score 1):

Put this to get your event :

```
if (!event)
    var event = window.event;
var code = event.which || event.keyCode;
```

It's different in IE and firefox

Comment: This is using jQuery which normalizes the event and passes it into the handlers as the first param. It also normalizes the event property which holds the information about the key which was pressed.

Comment: thanks but I don't know if it's really the event as when I hit enter in ie, the image that should be replaced by the ajaxLoader just desappears and the loader doesn't show up...

Answer (score 1):

As far as your image, it seems to me that the URL to the image would be `/images/ajaxLoader.gif` as `/dvt/public` seems like a doc root path. With the image on your server, what URL do you put in the browser view it? Also, you can pull the double quotes out of the `url()` in the CSS.

For the event and keycode, change the name of your event parameter (try `e` for starters) to avoid collision with the global namespace, then use `e.which`, per the [jQueryfn.keypress docs](http://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

Comment: I think you should then use `e.which`.

Comment: Thanks to all for the hints, the thing is that it's a zend application so I was using a view helper for the root path as echo $this->baseUrl(). I tried several relative paths (without double quotes) such as ../images/ajaxLoader.gif and /images/ajaLoader.gif. The only one that works in IE on the server is the full path: http://xxxx.org/dvt/public/images/ajaxLoader.gif